# Export lambda function Pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to javascript and typescript. Export Lambda function below is a export lambda function.

```
export const paintBoard = ( ) => ((console.log()), (console.log()))
```

in the function body, it has `console.log()` separate by comma, i do not understand how this function works. what is function pattern called?

When this lambda paintBoard function is called, this two `console.log()` is called  simultaneously or in sequence.

Comment: It's a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in this context and it does run in sequence.

Comment: (1,2,3,4) only returns 4, and console.log always returns undefined, so the full function will *always* give undefined